# Script code will display when click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a very, very simple image slider/slideshow with no autoplay. I only want to go to next or prev image on click. Having some issues as you can read below.

Problem : everytime I will click previous button it will display my javascript code

```js
var backgroundImage = new Array();
backgroundImage[0] = "images/image1.jpg";
backgroundImage[1] = "images/image2.jpg";
backgroundImage[2] = "images/image3.jpg";
backgroundImage[3] = "images/image4.jpg";
backgroundImage[4] = "images/image5.jpg";
backgroundImage[5] = "images/image6.jpg";
backgroundImage[6] = "images/image7.jpg";

function displayAllImages() {
  var i = 0,
    len = backgroundImage.length;
  for (; i < backgroundImage.length; i++) {

    var img = new Image();
    img.url = backgroundImage[i];
    img.style.width = '160px';
    img.style.height = '120px';

    document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
  }
};
displayAllImages();
$('.sp').first().addClass('active');
$('.sp').hide();
$('.active').show();
$('#button-next').click(function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
  if ($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
    $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
  }
  $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
  $('.sp').fadeOut();
  $('.active').fadeIn();
});
$('#button-previous').click(function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
  if ($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
    $('.sp').last().addClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
  }
  $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
  $('.sp').fadeOut();
  $('.active').fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" align="center">
  <div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="backgoundImage">
        <ul id="images"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container">

  <hr>
  <div id="nav" align="center">
    <div id="button-previous">
      <input id="prev_btn" type="button" name="prev_btn" value="Previous">
    </div>
    <div id="button-next">
      <input id="next_btn" type="button" name="next_btn" value="Next">
    </div>
  </div>
```

in this case, I want to ask if how can I add `div` tag with a `class=sp` and inside of it is the `img` tag.

Comment: Consider using sensible indentation while writing code - it'll make debugging and identifying blocks much easier.

Comment: Why you are using document.write and what javascript code you seeing when clicking on the back button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `image.src` instead of `image.url` and to add image in div, First create div, set attribute you want and append image in div

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('class', 'sp');

var img = new Image();
img.src = backgroundImage[i]; // img.url = backgroundImage[i];
img.style.width = '160px';
img.style.height = '120px';

div.appendChild(img); // Append Image in Div
```

After that use

```
document.getElementById('images').appendChild(div);
```

**Or** use like that

```
$('#images').append('<div class="sp"><img src="' + backgroundImage[i] + '" width="160px" height="120px" /></div>');
```

Comment: done .. I want to ask if how can I add div tag with a class=sp and inside of it is the img tag.

Comment: Updated, please check

Comment: If my answer works for you, please accept my answer , thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for (; i < backgroundImage.length; i++) {

    var img = new Image();
    img.url = backgroundImage[i];
    img.style.width = '160px';
    img.style.height = '120px';

    // //document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
    document.write("<div class=sp><img src='" + backgroundImage[i] + "' width='160' height='120'/></div>");
  }
```

First: in your for loop i ssuggest initializing i inside the for loop (but is optional):

```
for (var i =0; i < backgroundImage.length; i++) {
```

Second: **document.write(...);**

The write() method will replace the whole content of your document. Besides, it's inside a for loop, then, you are replacing the whole document with every iteration.
You should use the other approach: **appendChild()**. appendChild doesn't overwrite your document, it just adds an element inside another.

Try with appendChild, if you have more questions, update your questions or post a comment.

Comment: if I do appending only `document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);` it will only add img tag how about adding the div tag? with class sp? every img